# How to create bash script to launch CoffeeScript?

Tags: macos, bash, coffeescript

Here is my compile.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
coffee -o public/app/ -cwb public/src/
```

When i open script by double click:

```
File not found: public/src/.coffee
```

It is work only from terminal: ./compile.sh

May be there is best way to compile CoffeScript on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choroba is correct.

But instead of using full directory paths you could also get the current directory programmatically so you don't have to hard code any paths.

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
coffee -o $DIR/public/app/ -cwb $DIR/public/src/
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to get a coffeescript "script" to execute by "running it", similar to other scripts in a unix environment, you could try something like the following in your script, and make sure to set it to executable (`chmod a+x scriptname.coffee`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env coffee
path = require 'path'
fs = require 'fs'
...
```

At least that is how I launch executable coffeescript "scripts" at my end (a Linux system, but still...).

Comment: Don't work. I need script to run same comand from terminal: 
    coffee -o "public/app/" -cwb "public/src/"

Comment: I see, so you need to actually run the compile process when clicking, not run a compiled script itself. Sandro's answer is probably what you are looking for, but you may also want to consider the "watch" which allows the compiler to detect and compile changed scripts on demand.

Comment: This may not have been the subject of the original question, but it helped me creating a shell script using coffeescript. Thanks for that ;)

Answer (score 0):

When clicked, the script probably starts in a different folder. Use full paths in your script to make it universal.